# Linux script does not work when executed using the full path

Tags: linux, shell

I have an issue executing a script from another directory using a full path.

For example, user jnh has the script in its home directory(/home/jnh):
        # ls -l
        total 4
        -rwxr-x--- 1 jnh tstgrp 120 Mar 12 16:39 test.run

Now, when I log in as jnh and go to another directory such as /apps and execute the script using the full path, I got an error message:

```
# /home/jnh/test.run
touch: cannot touch `test.txt': Permission denied
```

Any idea? Thank you in advance!

Joie

Comment: Need more info on the 'touch' command in the script. Can you post the script code?

Comment: #! /bin/bash

touch test.txt
exit $?

Comment: Permissions of the current working directory?

Comment: Yep, it seem that user jnh isn't allowed to create files in /apps

Comment: Here's the permission of the current directory where the script is located: drwxrwxrwx 17 jnh  tstgrp 4096 Mar 12 17:10 jnh

Comment: It is where the script is executed from that matters

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is a permissions problem not a scripting problem. Does user jnh have write permission on the directory /apps? Because you are running the script from /apps it's the working directory, and thats where it is trying to create the file, so the user that is running the script must have permissions to do so.